# What happened to an answer that disappeared?

Tags: support, answers

I posted an answer today that disappeared into the Memory Hole.  Is there no way to tell what happened?  When I click on "activity", there's no sign of it.

**Later comment:** The question is again visible today, so I again know the title and the URL.  I didn't remember the title and didn't have the URL when I posted this comment.

Here it is: [Integral paradox: Deterministic integral interpreted as limiting case of stochastic integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102103/integral-paradox-deterministic-integral-interpreted-as-limiting-case-of-stochas)

So why the down-vote?  As I understand it, within "meta", that's supposed to express disagreement.  Why would anyone say they disagree with my question while not saying what they disagree with in it?

Comment: Answer to what question?

Comment: My guess is that the person who posted the question deleted it. That has the effect, indeed, of disappearing question, answers, comments and all into the Memory Hole.

Comment: Maybe instead of adding a dummy expression to get through the "quality standards" filter, you could try to improve the title. =)

Comment: Did it actually post? I wonder if there was some sort of internet connectivity error. (FWIW, I just glanced at the list of posts recently deleted by the owner and at the list of posts recently deleted by community, neither shows anything like you described; of course it may be that I missed something. It'd be easier for the moderators if you can describe what the content of the question and/or your answer is, including, preferably, searchable keywords.)

Comment: ....and now it's back today.   It was titled "integral paradox".

Comment: @Srivatsan : Specifically how could I have known that the _title_ was the reason the software posted that sarcastic comment?  (If in fact it was the reason?)

Comment: @Michael: I was not implying that I know for sure that the title is the culprit. I was doubtful myself, which was why I added the word "try". However the title was the first thing that struck me as odd about the post; and it would've been *my* first edit, in case I was the poster and the filter catches the post. [FWIW, I meant the comment with good intentions; just that I was a little surprised to find a one-word uninformative title from an experienced user of the site, who also actively works to improve the quality of posts.] Note: I neither upvoted nor downvoted the post.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez : I could have told you yesterday that the question was about stochastic integrals, but I couldn't have told you the title or the URL.

Comment: @Michael: If you *had* told us that the question was about stochastic integrals, then it would have been much easier to search for it.

Comment: Does a question temporarily disappear from view when someone is editing it?

Comment: It now seems unlikely that the source of the problem will be determined.  Some speculation: Is it possible that you had clicked on one of the tabs under activity, so that it only showed say, edits, or comments, and not answers?

Comment: @Jonas : I don't think so.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can think of is that the question was deleted and then restored, but I don't see any evidence of that on the question.

Other possibilities are that your answer was deleted and then restored, but there's no evidence of that either.

At this point I'd just chalk this up to a fluke.